# Lightning Network node collusion

Tags: lightning-network, fraud, lightning-routing, mastering-bitcoin

I' m learning about Bitcoin and LN enjoying Antonopoulos's excellent "Mastering Bitcoin" book

I stumbled upon Figure#7 in Chapter 12

https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/images/mbc2_1207.png

Would it be possible that instead of completing step 7, Diana sent R to Bob, that would then complete step 9 and only after that Diana complete step 7; leaving Carol scammed? I know LN routing is based on Sphinx; but that doesn't completely eliminate collusion, i.e. Bob and Diana being the same node operator that sees a payment to and from Carol for a similar amount, at a similar time

This could be prevented, IMHO using for instance multisig and revocation keys where R is just 1 of 2, being the other a channel-specific revocation key.